# for/in loop 2d array with one value ios does not return array but value

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, multidimensional-array

I want to get from a 2d array to a 1d array. I've got an array like so: `@[@["+9390902"]]` I've tried to make it like this: `@["+9390902"]` by doing a `for/in` loop as well as a regular `for` loop, but somehow I just end up with `"+9390902"` instead of the string nested in an Array. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Basically

```
for (NSArray *child in array) {

NSLog(@"Child array: %@",child);

}
```

returns `@"+9390902"` instead of `@[@"+9390902"]` while this is not expected at all.

Comment: In your for loop, try this: NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([child class])); If it logs NSArray in the console, then you can be sure it is an NSArray.

Comment: Update your question with the actual code that creates and populates `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question but here's an overview:

Suppose you have the array:

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@"+9390902"]];
```

(this can be represented also as):

```
NSArray *array = @[
    @[
        @"+9390902"
    ]
];
```

You can iterate over the values like so:

```
for (NSArray *child in array) {

    NSLog(@"Child array: %@",child);

}
```

Then, you can iterate through the child the same way.

```
for (NSString *string in child) {

    NSLog(@"Found string: %@",string);

}
```

You can also use subscripting to directly access the values if you know that they're there:

```
NSString *string = array[0][0];
```

Comment: Could you show where the array is created as well, what happens if you NSLog the array, and also what happens when you NSLog the child?